Best strategy to find the biggest value in i.i.d. random variables
Suppose we have i.i.d. random variables $\{X_k\}$ whose values are real numbers. We can determine the value of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ in order, and we can stop whenever we want. How to make our final result the biggest?
My friend told me this problem and claimed that we should stop whenever the value is bigger that first n/e variables. That sounds a really confimative strategy, but I have no clue how to prove it.

Your friend is likely referring to the Secretary problem, though it has a slightly different setup. E.g. in the setup you've described, if the $X_k$ are Bernoulli random variables then the optimal strategy is obviously to just stop as soon as you see a $X_k=1$.
